# Having a Base Class access a Child's members in C# Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, visibility

I'm sure I'm missing something since C# isn't my forte and I'm coming from a PHP background, but I'm writing a base class (called GVProgram) that will be inherited by child classes (ProgramA, ProgramB). I have the following:

```
public class GVProgram {
    public string path {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public GVProgram(string progpath) {
        path = progpath;
    }
    public Boolean isRunning() {
        return Process.GetProcesses().Any(prc => prc.ProcessName.Contains(name));
    }
}

public class ProgramA : GVProgram {
    public ProgramA(string progpath):base(progpath) {
        name = "Program A";
    }
}
```

When I call `ProgramA.isRunning()`, the debugger always complains that `name` is null. How do I get GVProgram to see the `name` member that is set inside ProgramA?

**Instatiation Code for Classes**

On my form class, I have:

```
private ProgramA progA;
private ProgramB progB;
```

When the form loads, I call:

```
this.progA = new ProgramA("C:\path\to\program");
this.progB = new ProgramB("C:\some\other\path");
```

The actual code for isRunning() getting called is this, which might be the problem (though I'm not sure how to get around it if it is):

```
private void refreshProgramAButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkProgramStatus(this.progA, this.programALabel, this.refreshProgramAButton);
}

protected void checkProgramStatus(GVProgram prog, Label label, Button button)
{
    if (prog.isRunning())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that checkProgramStatus is casting prog as GVProgram, not as the original class and not, as I expected, just using the GVProgram as type hinting to make sure the correct type of object is being passed?

**Breakpoints on isRunning**

I added a breakpoint to `if (prog.isRunning())` and added a Watch to `this.progA` and `prog` itself on the function.

`this.progA` is showing that `name` and `path` is set in base `prog` is showing that `name` and `path` are set in prog itself, and [ProgramA]->base. The call stack shows > `Program.exe!MyNamespace.GVProgram.isRunning() Line 28`

I changed isRunning to use `this.name` instead of just `name`. When I stepped into the function a second time, I put a watch on `this`. It too showed that `name` and `path` were correctly filled in.

**What Caused It**
It actually ended up being the constructor for ProgramB. It took a second parameter and that overloaded constructor wasn't setting the name. That's what I get for coding after midnight. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: That should work - are you sure you're instantiating ProgramA?

Comment: Yes, this should work. Can you show use the code that instantiates `ProgramA` and calls the `isRunning()` method?

Comment: Yup everything is correct here, name variable is getting its string, somthing must be wrong in the ProgramA's  instantiation

Comment: There's probably some code path in the instantiation of `ProgramA` that doesn't set `name` -- or `name` is getting set to `null` at some point.

Comment: It looks fine to me really (just make sure to use \\ in string literals to escape the backslashes, or prefix the literal with @, e.g. @"some\string").  Try setting a breakpoint after progA/progB are instantiated and verify that name has been set, and a breakpoint on isRunning so you can verify that it's still set.

Comment: Another thought, is there something called "name" in ProgramA as well?  If so, you're setting that instead of the one in the base class (the compiler would give you a warning about hiding an inherited member but it would still compile).

Comment: As a side note to the title: A base class accessing a child's members is a **very** big code smell. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your instantiating the wrong class. After adding your classes I wrote two programs.

This one fails with a null reference exception

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            GVProgram prog = new GVProgram();
            Console.WriteLine(prog.isRunning());
        }
    }
```

This one does not.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProgramA prog = new ProgramA("foo");
            Console.WriteLine(prog.isRunning());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make the GVProgram class 'abstract'. It might reveal the error (or at least help prevent similar errors in future).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The only way this would reveal the error is if `GVProgram` was being instantiated directly instead of `ProgramA` -- that would certainly cause the problem!

Comment: I set GVProgram as Abstract and I get the same result: the debugger complains that name is null.